# Circles in conformal geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

We know that conformal transformations of the Riemann sphere (which are general Mobius transformations) transform circles to circles. A similar fact is also true in higher dimensions. So we can say that circle is a concept in the conformal geometry of the spheres. Does there exist a more straightforward definition of circles in conformal geometry? and can one use this concept to give a more elementary proof of Liouville's theorem?

Comment: See the paper of Bailey and Eastwood on conformal circles: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1990-108-01/S0002-9939-1990-0994771-7/S0002-9939-1990-0994771-7.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Conformal geometry is an example of Cartan geometry of parabolic type (aka parabolic geometry) and there is a notion of distinguished curves for any parabolic geometry. See e.g. [On distinguished curves in parabolic geometries](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0308051) by A. Cap, J. Slovák, and V. Žádník or [Parabolic geodesics as parallel curves in parabolic geometries](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.4005) by Marc Herzlich. This not only gives definition for higher dimensions but also for general curved conformal manifolds and other examples of parabolic geometries.